# Change Button color with SharedPreferencers Android?

Tags: android, android-button, android-sharedpreferences

I would like to make a color change, done with a button, permanent using SharedPreferences. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gunawangsa);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Gunawangsa Hotel");

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gu_button);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ButtonDisable", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    final boolean isEnable = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ButtonDisable", true);
    button1.setEnabled(isEnable);
    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (button1.isClickable()) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Claim",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                boolean isEnable = sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("ButtonDisable", false).commit();
                if (isEnable == false) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Claim",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }


        }


    });

}
```

Comment: What you want actually?

Comment: I want if the button is clicked then the button changes permanently ??

Comment: permanentlly disable or want to change just color?

Comment: yes sir disable and change color sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class GunawangsaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1;

    boolean isEnable;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gunawangsa);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Gunawangsa Hotel");

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gu_button);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ButtonDisable", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        isEnable = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ButtonDisable", true);

        if (isEnable) {
            button1.setEnabled(true);
            button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            button1.setEnabled(false);
            button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Claim", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                editor.putBoolean("ButtonDisable", false);
                editor.commit();

                button1.setEnabled(false);
                button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
boolean isEnable = sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("ButtonDisable", false).commit();
```

with

```
boolean isEnable = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ButtonDisable", false);
sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("ButtonDisable",boolValue).apply();
```

Comment: thanks, but if I try close my aplication, my button color back first color.

Comment: below the boolean isEnable = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ButtonDisable", false); line add this: sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("ButtonDisable", boolvalue).apply();

Answer (score 0):

Well you do this:

```
button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

No matter what the value of the 'isEnable' is.

Try

```
button1.setBackgroundColor(isEnable ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
```